# Парсинг удаленной таблицы на react

Tags: html, reactjs, парсер, table

Есть сайт, на нем лежит обновляемая раз в день html таблица.

Мне нужно сделать страницу на react, которая будет брать определенный столбец из той таблицы, например, с надписью "абв-123" в ячейке, и выводить этот столбец целиком.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Таблица:

```html
<table width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
 <tbody>
 <tr> 
  <td width="6%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><strong> </strong></p> 
  </td>
  <td width="12%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><strong>Абв &mdash; 123</strong></p>
  </td> 
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><strong>Где &mdash; 456</strong></p>
  </td> 
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><strong>Жзи &mdash; 789</strong></p>
  </td> 
 </tr> 
 <tr> 
  <td rowspan="2" width="6%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em>1</em></p>
  </td>
  <td width="12%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><strong>Математика</strong></p>
   <p><em>
    <span style="margin-right: 0.3em"></span>
    <span style="margin-left: -0.3em">(Фамилия</span> И.О)
   </em></p>
  </td> 
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em> </em></p> 
  </td> 
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><strong>Математика</strong></p> 
   <p><em>
    <span style="margin-right: 0.3em"> </span> 
    <span style="margin-left: -0.3em">(Фамилия</span> И.О)
   </em></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
  <td width="12%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em> </em></p>
  </td> 
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em> </em></p> 
  </td> 
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em> </em></p> 
  </td>
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em> </em></p>
  </td>
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em> </em></p>
  </td> 
  <td width="10%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em> </em></p> 
  </td> 
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em> </em></p>
  </td>
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em> </em></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="2" width="6%" style="text-align: center;">
   <p><em>2</em></p> 
  </td>
  <td width="12%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><strong>Математика</strong></p>
   <p><em>
    <span style="margin-right: 0.3em"> </span>
    <span style="margin-left: -0.3em">(Фамилия</span> И.О.)
   </em></p>
  </td>
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><strong>Математика</strong></p>
   <p><em>
    <span style="margin-right: 0.3em"> </span>
    <span style="margin-left: -0.3em">(Фамилия</span> И.О.)
   </em></p>
  </td> 
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><strong>Математика</strong></p>
   <p><em>
    <span style="margin-right: 0.3em"> </span> 
    <span style="margin-left: -0.3em">(Фамилия</span> И.О.)
   </em></p> 
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
  <td rowspan="2" width="6%" style="text-align: center;">
   <p><em>3</em></p>
  </td>
  <td width="12%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><strong>Математика</strong></p>
   <p><em>
    <span style="margin-right: 0.3em"> </span> 
    <span style="margin-left: -0.3em">(Фамилия</span> И.О.)
   </em></p>
  </td>
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><strong>Математика</strong></p> 
   <p><em>
    <span style="margin-right: 0.3em"> </span> 
    <span style="margin-left: -0.3em">(Фамилия</span> И.О.)
   </em></p> 
  </td>
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><strong>Математика</strong></p> 
   <p><em>
    <span style="margin-right: 0.3em"> </span> 
    <span style="margin-left: -0.3em">(Фамилия</span> И.О.)
   </em></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
  <td width="12%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em> </em></p>
  </td>
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em> </em></p> 
  </td>
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em> </em></p>
  </td>
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em> </em></p>
  </td>
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em> </em></p>
  </td>
  <td width="10%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em> </em></p>
  </td>
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em> </em></p>
  </td>
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em> </em></p>
  </td>
 </tr> 
 <tr> 
  <td rowspan="2" width="6%" style="text-align: center;">
   <p><em>4</em></p> 
  </td>
  <td width="12%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em> </em></p>
  </td>
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><strong>Математика</strong></p> 
   <p><em>
    <span style="margin-right: 0.3em"> </span> 
    <span style="margin-left: -0.3em">(Фамилия</span> И.О.)
   </em></p>
  </td> 
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><strong> </strong></p>
  </td> 
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em> </em></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="12%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em> </em></p> 
  </td>
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em> </em></p>
  </td>
  <td width="11%" style="text-align: center;"> 
   <p><em> </em></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Делать get запрос на сайт и парсить данные из таблицы. Можете привести код таблицы или сайт, напишу конкретнее

Comment: @Gelloiss добавил таблицу

Comment: новая страница на том же сайте, что и таблица? если нет, то какие технологии можно испольчовать на сервере, где новая страница?

Comment: @Sergei таблица на удаленном сервере, новая страница -- сервер на nodejs, так что можно использовать все, что бесплатно и на js